# What does the word "there" refer to?

Tags: word-usage

He went to the nearest village and (
there) in the bazaar, he found various kinds of meat and fish.

Comment: Technically, the referent for "there" is "[in] the nearest village." The following phrase "in the bazaar" simply narrows the relevant portion of "the nearest village" to the place where the meat and fish were on offer.

Comment: Interesting question! I hope you end up getting a solid answer. :)

Comment: Also, consider: *"Here in the bazaar, he found various kinds of meat and fish".*

Comment: _There_ is a deictic word. It's part of a set of deictic words: _here, there, where, hither, thither, whither, hence, thence, whence,_ etc. Fillmore explains it in the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Answer (score -1):

It means: in, at, or to that place or position.

When "there" follows a location, it refers to that location. Example:

We went to London and stayed there ten days.

Your sentence can be written to:

He went to the nearest village and (in that village) in the bazaar, he found various kinds of meat and fish.

Comment: The word "there" means "in the nearest village", doesn't it? How about "in the bazaar"?

Comment: Yes, when "there"comes after a location - e.g. "in the nearest village", "London", it refers back to that place. "in the bazaar" means *inside* the village, there is a marketplace (bazaar).